# Trouble assembling raid1 array after replacing failed disk

Tags: raid, mdadm

I have a weird mdadm situation.

I had a drive in a raid1 array go bad.  I shut the machine down, and replaced the disk,  did ddrescue (which succeeded without error) from the old non-failed drive to the new drive.

Now when I attempt to assemble, I get:

```
% sudo mdadm --verbose --assemble /dev/md3 /dev/sdg1 /dev/sdf1
mdadm: looking for devices for /dev/md3                       
mdadm: /dev/sdg1 is identified as a member of /dev/md3, slot 0.
mdadm: /dev/sdf1 is identified as a member of /dev/md3, slot 0.
mdadm: no uptodate device for slot 1 of /dev/md3
mdadm: added /dev/sdg1 to /dev/md3 as 0
mdadm: /dev/md3 assembled from 0 drives and 1 rebuilding - not enough to start the array.
```

and my `cat /proc/mdstat` is

```
md3 : inactive sdf1[0](S)
      7813894144 blocks super 1.2
```

output of examine

```
% sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sd[fg]1                                                                                                       21-08-21 - 12:13:27
/dev/sdf1:                         
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x2
     Array UUID : 1a5dd664:54cdc95a:f0de5ce2:c8ea58f9
           Name : arcana:3  (local to host arcana)
  Creation Time : Wed Jan 18 14:06:34 2017
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 15627788288 (7451.91 GiB 8001.43 GB)
     Array Size : 7813893952 (7451.91 GiB 8001.43 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 15627787904 (7451.91 GiB 8001.43 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
Recovery Offset : 0 sectors
   Unused Space : before=261864 sectors, after=384 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 5501a6d9:dfef5dbf:aae0b1cb:4692e6ec

    Update Time : Fri Aug 13 11:19:08 2021
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 264 sectors
       Checksum : 2b596499 - correct
         Events : 2777


   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdg1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x2
     Array UUID : 1a5dd664:54cdc95a:f0de5ce2:c8ea58f9
           Name : arcana:3  (local to host arcana)
  Creation Time : Wed Jan 18 14:06:34 2017
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 15627788288 (7451.91 GiB 8001.43 GB)
     Array Size : 7813893952 (7451.91 GiB 8001.43 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 15627787904 (7451.91 GiB 8001.43 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
Recovery Offset : 0 sectors
   Unused Space : before=261864 sectors, after=384 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 5501a6d9:dfef5dbf:aae0b1cb:4692e6ec

    Update Time : Fri Aug 13 11:19:08 2021
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 264 sectors
       Checksum : 2b596499 - correct
         Events : 2777


   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

I want to get this fixed (hopefully without losing any data).  It seems like for the slots, one should be `0` and one should be `1`.  How do I get this going?  My googling has failed me and I don't want to "just try things" because I am a bit shy about destroying the data.

Comment: If you only need to change the number, then [this answer from a few years back](https://askubuntu.com/a/259084/1222991) should do what you need to do.

Comment: I don't think that will work with the metadata version I have, I get `mdadm: --update=super-minor not understood for 1.x metadata`